# Initialization difference between these two bits of code

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

I am attempting to build a char array from a function that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void construct_buf(char* buf)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        buf += snprintf(buf, 9, "01234567");
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char buf[65] = {0};
    construct_buf(buf);
    printf("<%.64s>\n", buf);
}
```

Where the `buf` parameter is the empty char array that will be constructed by this function. The problem (as far as I know) is with char array/pointer initialization.

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char buf[65] = {0};
    construct_buf(buf);
    printf("<%.64s>\n", but);
}
```

I am under the impression that `arr = {0}` fills the array with zeroes, according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) page, where it states:

```
int z[3] = {0}; // z has type int[3] and holds all zeroes
```

But `valgrind --track-origins=yes ./out` says:

```
==51611== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==51611== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==51611== Using Valgrind-3.18.0.GIT-lbmacos and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==51611== Command: ./out
==51611== 
==51611== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff2009c000, 0x80001fe9c000) (defined)
==51611== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff2009c000, 0x7fff7fd64000) (defined)
==51611== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff8e2f0000, 0x7fffc009c000) (noaccess)
==51611== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fffc009c000, 0x7fffe2ebc000) (defined)
==51611== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fffe2ebc000, 0x7fffffe00000) (noaccess)
==51611== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==51611==    at 0x7FFF203ED91A: ??? (in /dev/ttys002)
==51611==    by 0x7FFF202BB194: ??? (in /dev/ttys002)
==51611==    by 0x7FFF202C3E3B: ??? (in /dev/ttys002)
==51611==    by 0x7FFF202E8974: ??? (in /dev/ttys002)
==51611==    by 0x7FFF202C0FF5: ??? (in /dev/ttys002)
==51611==    by 0x7FFF202BF165: ??? (in /dev/ttys002)
==51611==    by 0x100003617: main (main.c:21)
==51611==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==51611==    at 0x100011025: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==51611== 
<0123456701234567012345670123456701234567012345670123456701234567>
==51611== 
==51611== HEAP SUMMARY:
==51611==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==51611==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==51611== 
==51611== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==51611== 
==51611== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==51611== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Valgrind does not complain when I write this:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char* buf = calloc(65, sizeof *buf);
    construct_buf(buf);
    printf("<%.64s>\n", but);
}
```

In the first example, when `buf` is passed to the function, `char[]` will decay to `char*`. If `= {0}` initializes the entire array, how is that different from explicitly allocating space with a pointer?

I am compiling with

```
clang -g -Wall -o main.o -c main.c
clang -g -Wall -o out main.o
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237506/discussion-on-question-by-gmdev-initialization-difference-between-these-two-bits).

Answer (score 0):

> how is that different from explicitly allocating space with a pointer?

1. From the `construct_buf` function point of view there is no difference.
2. From the caller's point of view:

a. `calloc` version creates two objects. One is pointer, the second one is the allocated memory block. Using it requires additional memory read (as first has to be read the address of the allocated block, then you can access the allocated buffer). On many occasions it is less efficient.

b.`calloc` version memory has to be freed by the programmer.

c. both versions will be placed in the different memory segments.

d. `calloc`ed memory can be accessed outside the scope it was allocated.

Comment: None of this explains the valgrind error.